# Can't login with AD account

Tags: active-directory

I can't login with an AD user account with freshly installed Ubuntu 21.10 (also tried 20.04). `id <AD user>` works like expected. When I try to login ubuntu keeps saying "can`t login with pass" (I believe the translation is correct, I am on Russian locale).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmqCT.png)

Comment: Sure it does not say wrong password?

Comment: yes, i`m sure. password correct